# Particle in a box - speed probability distribution

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, observables

Consider a particle in a box with infinite barriers. By solving the Schrödinger we can find the probability of finding the particle at some points in the box. How can we find the probability of particle having some speed?

Comment: [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_box#Momentum_wave_function).

Answer (score 1):

You will have to settle for *momentum* since *speed* is not a quantum mechanical observable (because $\dot{x}$ is *not* a classical observable on the phase space, which are functions of $x$ and $p$, but a function of a classical trajectory $(x(t),p(t))$, so canonical quantization does not produce a "speed" observable).

The probability for a certain momentum, however, is given by $\lvert \phi(p) \rvert^2$ where $\phi(p)$ is just the Fourier transform of the position wavefunction $\psi(x)$.

Comment: Is there other way of finding the probability for a certain momentum without Fourier transform?

Comment: @SebiSebi: No, not really, because you will have to use that $\langle p \vert x \rangle = \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}px}$ for a momentum eigenstate $\langle p \rvert$ and a position eigenstate $\langle x \rvert$, and everything you do with that will amount to doing the Fourier transform.

Comment: Heisenberg uncertainty principle could be useful to get an approximation for momentum distribution?

Comment: No, because the uncertainty principal is an inequality.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say how many dimensions this is in - so lets take 1D and the ground state.
More dimensions and higher states follow the same argument.

The wave function is proportional to $\sin(kx)\equiv \sin({\pi x \over a})$ where $a$ is the length of the  side of the box. And $k=p/\hbar.$

But $\sin(kx)={1 \over 2 i} (e^{i k x}-e^{-i kx})$. This is the superposition of 2 states with wavenumbers $k$ and $-k$.

So we do actually know the speed exactly(!) It is $\hbar \pi \over m a$. What we don't know is the velocity, as this speed can be positive or negative, with a probability of 0.5 for each.

Incidentally, taking $\hbar \pi \over a$ as the uncertainty in momentum and $a \over \sqrt{12} $ as the uncertainty in position,  the product gives  $\Delta_p \Delta_x={\pi \over \sqrt{12}} \hbar\geq {\hbar \over 2}$, conforming with the Heisenberg uncertainty principle.